# Strong markov property of a transformation of the Brownian motion

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, markov-process

Let $(B_t)$ be a standard Brownian motion and consider $(X_t)$ defined as:
$$X_t=e^{-t}B_{e^{2t}}$$
I've proved that this process is markov, however I can't prove that is strong markov. I know that this seem like the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process but I don't know anything about SDE that probably will solve this problem easly.